# Merge column of two tables without relationship

Tags: mysql

I need to merge columns of two tables with different rows. It should put `NULL` value into table with less rows.

**Example :**

Assume these two simple tables :

**table_one**

```
+----+-----------+---------------------+
| id | title     | date                |
+----+-----------+---------------------+
| 10 | Good      | 2014-10-08 05:13:00 |
| 11 | NotBad    | 2014-10-24 00:00:00 |
| 12 | Excellent | 2014-10-26 14:00:00 |
| 13 | Bad       | 2014-10-11 19:31:23 |
+----+-----------+---------------------+
```

**table_two**

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | Sara |
|  2 | Alex |
+----+------+
```

**What output I need :**

```
+----+-----------+---------------------+------+------+
| id | title     | date                |  id  | name |
+----+-----------+---------------------+------+------+
| 10 | Good      | 2014-10-08 05:13:00 |   1  | Sara |
| 11 | NotBad    | 2014-10-24 00:00:00 |   2  | Alex |
| 12 | Excellent | 2014-10-26 14:00:00 | NULL | NULL |
| 13 | Bad       | 2014-10-11 19:31:23 | NULL | NULL |
+----+-----------+---------------------+----+------+
```

**What I've tried so far :**

```
SELECT table_one.*, table_two.* FROM table_one, table_two
```

But that's not my desire! It will return Cartesian Product

P.S :

These two tables has not any relationship between each other.

Comment: table_one and table_two have Fk?

Comment: Use a `left join`. See [this explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: @juergend These two tables has not any relationship between each other

Comment: why is sarah good nd alex is just not bad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assume the first table has more rows, you can do this by generating a key using variables:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from (select t1i.*, (@rn1 := @rn1 + 1) as rn
      from table_one t1i cross join (select @rn1 := 0) vars
     ) t1 left join
     (select t2i.*, (@rn2 := @rn2 + 1) as rn
      from table_two t2i cross join (select @rn2 := 0) vars
     ) t2
     on t1.rn = t2.rn;
```

You will have two surplus columns called `rn`, if you don't need that, list your columns instead of `select t1.*, t2.*`.